# XmlHttpRequest and threads in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, xmlhttprequest, delphi-2010

I use Delphi 2010 and when I try to perform an XmlHttpRequest operation inside a separate thread from my application, I get an EOleSysError exception with the following message:
'CoInitialize has not been called, ClassID: {F6D90F16-9C73-11D3-B32E-00C04F990BB4}'

Anyone have any ideas to fix this?
(Sorry for my bad English)

Thanks!

Comment: CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx must be called for every thread which is using COM object

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call CoInitialize at the beginning of your thread's Execute method.  Don't forget to call CoUninitialize at the end of Execute.

Chris Bensen wrote some [blog posts about this](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2007/06/delphi-tips-and-tricks_20.html).

Comment: Not the thread's constructor. That runs in the context of the caller creating the thread, not in the context of the new thread. Initialize and uninitialize COM in the Execute method.

Comment: +1 don't forget Ariel, try CoInitialize; (* code to be ran *) finally CoUninitialize; end;